# ansible win_copy cannot copy src file as it does not exist

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a molecule test where it is supposed to create a VM and copy a binary from network UNC path to the VM but somehow it is failing with the below mentioned error. This is what the task looks like

```
- name: Copy mysql_hg binary from network share
  ansible.windows.win_copy:
    src: "\\\\someshare.example.com\\somefolder\\mysql_hg.exe"
    dest: "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\mysql_hg.exe"
    remote_src: True
  vars:
    #ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true
    ansible_become: True
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
    ansible_become_user: "someaduser@example.com"
    ansible_become_password: "adpass of someaduser"
```

```
<172.16.4.59> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: mol_user on PORT 5986 TO 172.16.4.59
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
Using module file /usr/share/ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/modules/win_copy.ps1
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
fatal: [MOL_INST]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "dest": "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\mysql_hg.exe",
    "msg": "Cannot copy src file: '\\\\someshare.example.com\\somefolder\\mysql_hg.exe' as it does not exist",
    "src": "\\\\someshare.example.com\\somefolder\\mysql_hg.exe"
}
```

How to make it work?

I mentioned the task file which I am using. I found a few similar issues while googling but that didn't solve my problem. I want to get the task working

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got permission to the network share you trying to connect to?

or else try and putting other username/pass into the task

```
- name: copy file from UNC path
  win_copy:
    src: \\someshare.example.com\share\mysql_hg.exe
    dest: C:\Windows\Temp\mysql_hg.exe
    remote_src: yes
  become: True
  become_method: runas
  become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=netcredentials_only
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: someuserwithaccess
    ansible_become_pass: someruserspassword
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still it is not working